# Laravel - Routing error

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I am a beginner with Laravel (5.2) and so if this is obvious I apolgise. I have an entry in a Post controller to delete an entry which is passed:

```
public function getDeletePost( $post_id )
    {

            $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();
            $post->delete();
            $message = "successfully deleted";
            return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with( ['message'=> $message] );
    }
```

which is called from a function in the routes file:

```
Route::get('/delete-post/{post_id}',
            [ 'uses'=> 'PostController@getDeletePost',
             'as' => 'post.delete' ]);
```

The route is called from a page:

```
<a href="{{   route('post.delete',['post_id' => $post->id] )  }}">delete</a>
```

The page is showing the correct URL (http://localhost:8000/post-delete/5) but I am getting the following error and cannot seem to get around it:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('D:\websites\__laravel\socialnetwork\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Is it just a typo here in your post, that your route is called `delete-post` and the URL that is created is `post-delete`?

Comment: Now I feel suitably embarrased. Yes it was a typo on my part. Laravel looks awesome but a bit of mindset when you come from a procedural background. Thanks. I have spent hours on this and you fix it in minutes! Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome. I am glad that this fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a typo! I am suitably humbled!